# Python code to execute multiple stored procs parallely

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a python program that connects to five different Oracle databases and executes stored procedures in sequence and stores the output in corresponding tables. The data stored in all the tables is then written to a single text file. Each stored procs takes about 30 minutes to complete. Since all the stored procs runs in sequence it takes atlease 2 hours and 30 minutes for the python program complete.

1. Oracle DATABASE1 - sp_count_procedure1 - Output_table1
2. Oracle DATABASE2 - sp_count_procedure2 - Output_table2
3. Oracle DATABASE3 - sp_count_procedure3 - Output_table3
4. Oracle DATABASE4 - sp_count_procedure4 - Output_table4
5. Oracle DATABASE5 - sp_count_procedure5 - Output_table5

Instead of executing the stored procedures in sequence one after the other, i want to execute all five stored procs parallely. the data from all the five output table are then written to single text file.

Please help me how i can execute all 5 stored procs parallely so i can reduce the overall python code execution time. If all 5 stored procs can be executed parallely then i can reduce the python code execution to 30 to 40 minutes.

Comment: Does the order of the data in the output file matter?

Comment: I guess that multi-threading should be enough for this. Read the docs about the "threading" module.

Comment: Order doesn’t really matter.

Comment: Assuming the stored procedure runs for 30 minutes and then all the resulting data is written to the output file (could it be otherwise?), then if you run all the stored procedures in parallel you must serialize writing to the output file since two or more stored threads/processes could be attempting to write to the file at the same. So one way to handle this is to use file locking. Or if the amount of data is not that large, each thread/process could return the data back to the main thread, which does all the file outputting.